# react-addons-* what does this signify?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was working on a project and saw in package.json things like

> 1. react-addons-shallow-compare
> 2. react-addons-css-transition-group
> 3. react-addons-pure-render-mixin

and if you go to these modules in the project after installing the packages you find npm stuff and an index.js file

```
module.exports = require('react/lib/shallowCompare');
```

so basically they are importing stuff from react/react-dom packages and exporting them globally

```
"peerDependencies": {
"react": "^15.4.2"
},
```

they have react in there peer dependencies which is same or above as the version of these modules in package.json

So my question is what is the reason for this as react could have exported these things on its own.

So are these those things whose code will soon be removed from the main react/react-dom package and hence just as a warning these are separated out like this or is it for sharing these things globally?

Is there some software mathodology being followed here that I am not aware of?

Comment: The three examples you mention have all been deprecated and so will probably be removed from React at some point. Having these separate packages helps with backward compatibility - when they are removed from the main React codebase, the code can be moved over there and your app will continue to work. The open-source community can continue to maintain the packages if there's sufficient interest.

Comment: no not talking about these only in general is this the way to deprecate elements of a library? or is there some standard blog/document about this?

Comment: Hm, it's *a* way to deprecate a module, and it seems to be the one React has chosen to follow, but I'm not sure if I know of an authoritative source on this. This is an interesting subject though, I hope others come along with more info!